# doxygen Call graph does not work

Tags: doxygen

I have installed doxygen and graphviz-2.38 on my windows 7. But when i generate Call graphs or Called graphs, the png file or the graphs does not open,  it generates .md5 file but searches for .png files for the graphs . Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Doxygen can use the "dot" tool from graphviz to generate more advanced diagrams and graphs. 
If you have the "dot" tool in the path, you can set HAVE_DOT to YES in the configuration file to let doxygen use it. Among the dot options, use DOT_IMAGE_FORMAT also.
The DOT_IMAGE_FORMAT tag can be used to set the image format of the images generated by dot. Possible values are svg, png, jpg, or gif. If left blank png will be used.
Note
If you choose svg you need to set HTML_FILE_EXTENSION to xhtml in order to make the SVG files visible in IE 9+ (other browsers do not have this requirement).